# Word cannot undo this action. Do you want to continue?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document into which I copy all kinds of VBA code regarding questions asked on this site and write code in preparation for answers. This document was created on my PC (with Word 2010). It has no event procedure that runs on the Save event, but at some point a few weeks back it started to ask me the above question before every save, including automatic saves. The document is based on the Normal template which has no code in it. I don't know which code may have caused this to start, nor which code to even suspect. Other documents open in the same instance of Word save normally. It's only this one document that is affected.

The document also contains a lot of special items, like content controls, fields, ActiveX controls, EndNotes, tables and comments. I suspect the comments to be related to this problem in some way.

I know that I could probably stop the alerts by disabling alerts but that isn't what I want. I want Word to display all the normal alerts. It's just this abnormal one which I would like to switch off. Any ideas how to do that? Or what caused Word to issue that alert in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these situations I make several backups of the document and then start looking for something that is broken.  So using a new backup each time, I systematically delete portions of the document to see if the unwanted / unexpected behavior disappears. For example I first try to isolate the issue to the top of bottom 1/2 of the document. If I can establish that the issue is related to the bottom half then I delete half of the bottom half of the document and so on... it can take a while but it has been an effective method of finding issues for me.

That said, I tried this on a document recently and just ended up going round in circles.  I thought I had narrowed the issue down to a single corrupt image, but that turned out to be NOT the case.

I've also found that there are some things that I can do with VBA that Word simply can NOT undo... I'm only aware of a few things (which I'd have to look up in my notes) but I'm sure there's a whole list of things.

A possible workaround might be to clear the undo history for this specific document prior to saving, I imagine that will suppress the message and save you from losing the standard notifications.  Hope it helps :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem. I agree that finding out what causes the message might bring me one step nearer to an answer, but I suppose the real question is which changes can be undone after Save. My understanding is that the answer is none. If all changes become permanent after Save, what's the point of informing me that some of them, unspecified, are actually "more undoable" than all the undoable others?

Comment: But... if you take a new document add content, then save you generally CAN undo then edits... there are perhaps some things that can happen to a document that can't be undone after a save (perhaps field updates, but would have to check).  Anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: Yes. That's true. I guess that would then answer my question entirely. Thank you.